# Number of times trigger has executed

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm trying to save the number of times a trigger has fired into a database table but I can't find anything in the quartz-scheduler.net regarding this. Is there any method I can invoke to achieve this?

With simple trigger, there's a .GetTimesTriggered() method. Is there any equivalent for the cron triggers?

Comment: You can handle it by yourself, in the trigger method you may increment an external counter, like in a database or a static variable somewhere, if you use a static variable, don't forget to use the lock

Comment: Any Success MO Mi?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement ISchedulerListener. 
I have implemented it like following for some logging on trigger execution

```
    public class QuartzSchedulerListener : ISchedulerListener//todo R & D to catch schdeuler error/invalid shutdown event and do possible implementation there
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public Task JobScheduled(ITrigger trigger, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler JobScheduled");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task JobUnscheduled(TriggerKey triggerKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler JobUnscheduled");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task TriggerFinalized(ITrigger trigger, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler TriggerFinalized");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task TriggerPaused(TriggerKey triggerKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler TriggerPaused");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task TriggersPaused(string triggerGroup, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.DebugFormat("Quartz Scheduler TriggersPaused {0}", triggerGroup);

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task TriggerResumed(TriggerKey triggerKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler TriggersPaused");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task TriggersResumed(string triggerGroup, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.DebugFormat("Quartz Scheduler TriggersResumed {0}", triggerGroup);

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task JobAdded(IJobDetail jobDetail, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler JobAdded");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task JobDeleted(JobKey jobKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler JobDeleted");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task JobPaused(JobKey jobKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler JobPaused");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task JobInterrupted(JobKey jobKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler JobInterrupted");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task JobsPaused(string jobGroup, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.DebugFormat("Quartz Scheduler JobsPaused {0}", jobGroup);

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task JobResumed(JobKey jobKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler JobResumed");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task JobsResumed(string jobGroup, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.DebugFormat("Quartz Scheduler JobsResumed {0}",jobGroup);

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task SchedulerError(string msg, SchedulerException cause, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.DebugFormat("Quartz Scheduler is Error State message:{0}", msg);
            if (cause != null)
            {
                Logger.Error(cause);
            }
        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task SchedulerInStandbyMode(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler is in Stand By Mode");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task SchedulerStarted(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler is Started");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task SchedulerStarting(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler is Starting");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task SchedulerShutdown(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler is Shut Down");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task SchedulerShuttingdown(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler is Shutting Down");

        });
        return t;
    }

    public Task SchedulingDataCleared(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
        (() =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Quartz Scheduler SchedulingDataCleared");

        });
        return t;
    }
}



  StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                var MyQuartzScheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
                QuartzSchedulerListener olistener = new QuartzSchedulerListener();
                MyQuartzScheduler.ListenerManager.AddSchedulerListener(olistener);
                await MyQuartzScheduler.Start();
```